# Double integration on $D=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 :\sqrt{x}\leq y \leq 2\sqrt{x},\ x^2\leq y \leq 4x^2 \rbrace$. Am I right?

Tags: integration, multiple-integral

The problem is to integrate $x^{-3}$ on the region $D=\lbrace (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : \sqrt{x}\leq y \leq 2\sqrt{x},\ x^2\leq y \leq 4x^2 \rbrace$. I want to know if my attempt is good: Since the most 'lefted' point of $D$ is $(1/16)^{1/3}$ (this comes from the common point of $y=4x^2$ and $y=\sqrt{x}$) and the most 'righted' is $4^{1/3}$ (this come from the common point of $y=2\sqrt{x}$ and $y=x^2$).

$$ \int \int _D \frac{1}{x^3}\ dxdy = \int_{(1/16)^{1/3}} ^{4^{1/3}} \int _{\sqrt{x}}^{2\sqrt{x}} \frac{1}{x^3} \ dydx$$

Am I right? thanks in advance.

EDIT: I don't care about the solution, I can do that integral by myself. I only want to assure if the limits that I put in both integrals are correct.

Comment: I will not agree with your limits. I will suggest to draw a sketch for $D$.

Comment: The region is far more complicated than you think. Indeed, draw a sketch. Maybe a change of variables is called for. Where did you encounter this?

Comment: You should split the region $D$ in three parts and calculate three double integrals.

Comment: @Angelo: Much better: Make the appropriate change of variables and integrate over a rectangle!  It yells that loudly.

Comment: @TedShifrin, you are right. Let $\,X=\frac y{x^2}\,,\,Y=\frac y{\sqrt x}\,.\,$ It results that $D=\lbrace (X,Y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : 1\leqslant Y\leqslant2\,,\,1\leqslant X\leqslant4\rbrace$. Moreover $\,\frac1{x^3}=\frac{X^2}{Y^2}\,.$

Comment: Let the OP finish. The Jacobian determinant needs to be computed ….

Comment: @TedShifrin, is the Jacobian determinant equal to $-\frac{2Y}{3X^2}\,?$ Could you verify if I am right? Is the final result of the double integral $\,2\ln2\,?\,$

Comment: Alternatively, substituting either $x\mapsto ax$ or $y\mapsto by$ for a suitable constant $a,b$ will make the region symmetric, and subsequent conversion to polar coordinates makes for a manageable integral.